# How to dynamically store address of a QVector<T> in another QVector<QVector<T>*>?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, c++17

I am working with large amounts of data, something like 100,000 double values, being gathered every 100 milliseconds or so. I have to store 25 or even more of these generated data in my software at any given time. Both, the data length on each acquisition as well as the number of acquisitions varies depending on the current situation. I do not want to store my data as `QVector<QVector<double>>` because `QVector` stores data in adjacent memory locations and each addition of `QVector<double>` to `QVector<QVector<double>>` results in the entire thing being copied to a new location given, resulting in huge lags (especially if there is already 20 `QVector<double>` present and I am adding the 21st one to it).

My solution is to store the given data as `QVector<QVector<double>*>` i.e. each data acquisition  I am just storing the address to the `QVector` for the current acquisition. However, I want it to be stored in `QVector<QVector<double>*>` independently i.e. as long as I don't clear the pointer I am able to access the data. I am unable to figure out how to do this. I have tried multiple methods. Let's say I declare `QVector<QVector<double>*> myVec;` in my **.h** file and I use a function to new add data to it on each acquisition like this (below function is just for testing, that's why I am creating data inside the function):

```
void MainWindow::addData()
{
    myVec << &QVector<double>(0) // Creating a new empty vector and storing it's location
    *myVec[0] << 2.7 << 3.4 << 4.5;
}
```

This doesn't work, most of the time it throws an exception, and a few times it just shows some garbage value.

```
void MainWindow::addData()
{
    QVector<double> tempVec; // Create a temprory vector
    tempVec << 2.7 << 3.4 << 4.5;
    myVec << &tempVec;
}
```

This also doesn't work, of course, because `tempVec` is destroyed as soon as `addData()` is exited.

```
void MainWindow::addData()
{
    QVector<double> tempVec; // Create a temprory vector
    tempVec << 2.7 << 3.4 << 4.5;
    myVec << &QVector(tempVec);
}
```

I thought this would work as I am not storing the address of `tempVec` but rather copying `tempVec` in a new `QVector` and assigning its address to `myVec`, but it is also throwing an exception.

Is there any way I can store `QVector` **purely as pointers** inside another `QVector` ?

Comment: No, each addition to a vector does ***not*** cause reallocation. A rather smart algorithm results in reallocation happening in constant amortized time.

Comment: Resizing a QV of QV doesn't copy all of the data it just moves pointers around.  Something else is your problem.  Possibly you are copying the QV?  Don't.

Comment: @Yakk - Adam Nevraumont Thanks! Yes, I am copying a QV from my data source to my calculation algorithm because I want each of these to function independently of each other.

Comment: @Chaitanya move it instead of copying it?  Or do you need two logical copies of it?

Comment: @Yakk I need 2 logical copies of it, one to show the data in a plot and another to do the calculations. I want the plot to have an independent copy so that even if I clear the data in the calculation part the plot does not throw an exception. I guess I can just use QV<QV<T>> if it just stores QV as pointers.

Comment: @Chaitanya It stores as pointers, but it might duplicate if you duplicate.

Comment: Can't you switch to standard containers? You have good control over when things are reallocated, also you have `deque` or `list` there when you need.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt I can, I am very new to C++ and I started with `Qt` that's why I am using `QVector` but after going through the comments here I think standard containers will be better suited for me, especially a combination of `std::vector` with `std::move`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing addresses to objects that are then destroyed. That means your vector of pointers contains dangling pointers:

```
void MainWindow::addData()
{
    myVec << &QVector<double>(0);
    // the temporary vector is destroyed here and myVec contains a
    // dangling pointer
    *myVec[0] << 2.7 << 3.4 << 4.5;
}
```

I'm surprised your compiler even accepts this code, since taking the address of a temporary should be a compilation error. Naming the temporary allows it to compile, but it's not any better, since you still get a dangling pointer:

```
void MainWindow::addData()
{
    QVector<double> tempVec(0);
    myVec << &tempVec;
    *myVec[0] << 2.7 << 3.4 << 4.5;
} // <-- tempVec is destroyed here, so you get a dangling pointer
```

If you store a pointer to an object, you need to make sure this object still exists whenever you access that pointer.

One way around this would be to allocate each vector with `new` before storing its address. But then you need to remember to `delete` it when you no longer need the pointers. Instead of that, you can use a smart pointer instead. `std::unique_ptr` in this case would do the job, but unfortunately `QVector` cannot store non-copyable elemens. So you'd need `std::shared_ptr`. This way, you don't need to store the pointers anywhere else but `myVec`:

```
#include <memory>

QVector<std::shared_ptr<QVector<double>>> myVec;

// ...

void MainWindow::addData()
{
    myVec << std::make_shared<QVector<double>>(0);
    *myVec[0].get() << 2.7 << 3.4 << 4.5;
}
```

If you don't absolutely require `QVector` and can do with `std::vector` instead, I'd recommend that, since it can store `std::unique_ptr` elements just fine:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<QVector<double>>> myVec;

// ...

void MainWindow::addData()
{
    myVec.push_back(std::make_unique<QVector<double>>(0));
    *myVec[0].get() << 2.7 << 3.4 << 4.5;
}
```

If you really need to store raw pointers and can't use smart pointers, then I'm afraid you need to manage the pointed-to objects yourself by allocating them with `new` and then once you're done with `myVec` and no longer need it, clean up with `delete`:

```
QVector<QVector<double>*> myVec;

// ...

void MainWindow::addData()
{
    myVec << new QVector<double>(0);
    *myVec[0] << 2.7 << 3.4 << 4.5;
}

// Cleanup code you need to call when you no longer need myVec
for (auto ptr : myVec) {
    delete ptr;
}
```

Keep in mind that you also need to delete a pointer if you remove it from `myVec` or override it with a different pointer. This is tedious and error prone. When you forget to do it, you leak memory. So I recommend going the `unique_ptr` route instead, which will automatically delete the pointer for you.

Finally, and this might be preferable in your case, you can avoid pointers altogether and **move** the vector into `myVec` by casting it to an rvalue using `std::move()`. Not sure how well `QVector` works with move semantics, but `std::vector` does the job just fine, in which case you'd use `std::vector` for both "inner" and "outer" vectors. As an optimization, if you know the amount of doubles you need to store, you can pre-allocate with `reserve()` to avoid costly re-allocations when you add elements:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<double>> myVec;

// ...

void MainWindow::addData()
{
    std::vector<double> tmpVec;
    tmpVec.reserve(amount_of_elements);
    
    tmpVec.push_back(2.4);
    tmpVec.push_back(3.7);
    // etc until filled

    myVec.push_back(std::move(tmpVec));
}
```

With moving, no allocations or copies are performed, if the objects involved support move semantics. As mentioned, `std::vector` does.

Very important: after an object has been "moved from" (`tmpVec` in this case), it's in a valid but unspecified state (usually empty.)

Comment: Thanks! I will try these. I don't absolutely need `QVector` so I will try with `std::vector` as well, all I need is to read data once I have stored it and then clear it as soon as I have no use of it.

Comment: @Chaitanya Since performance is important in your case, I added a way that uses move-semantics to avoid storing pointers altogether and get rid of reallocations and copies at the same time.

Comment: @ Nikos C. This is great! I am new to C++ and not yet used either `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` or move semantics. I will try it now in my algorithms. Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for as I try to avoid direct pointers as much as possible and use iterators instead to access values. Using move semantics will be the best in this case.

Comment: @Chaitanya If you've never dealt with move semantics before, I recommend a two-part CppCon 2019 talk by Klaus Iglberger: [part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=St0MNEU5b0o), [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIzaZbKUw2s)